# how to use mockReturnValue to return different value inside different test React

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, next.js, react-testing-library

I am writing a unit test including multiple tests. for each of the test I need to use `mockReturnValue` to mock the returned value (I want the `status` property to be different in different test) of an imported api function.

My code:

```
import userEvent from '@testing-library/user-event'
import { renderWithWrappers, screen, waitFor } from '@/tests/testUtils'
import { getUserDetails, updateUser } from '@/controllers/Users'
import { LANG } from '@/constants'
import EditUserModal from '../EditUserModal'

const { EN } = LANG

jest.mock('@/controllers/Users')

describe('EditUserModal', () => {
  afterEach(() => {
    jest.clearAllMocks()
  })

  const props = {
    id: 123,
    show: true,
    onHide: jest.fn(),
    mutate: jest.fn(),
    roles: [
      { value: 111, label: 'Low', allowPortalAccess: 0 },
      { value: 123, label: 'High', allowPortalAccess: 1 }
    ]
  }
  const data = {
    first_name: 'Jean Gold',
    last_name: 'SD',
    lang: 'FR',
    role_id: 111
  }

  const mockState = {
    user: {
      credentials: { id: 12345 }
    }
  }

  it('renders modal header and close icon correctly', async () => {
    getUserDetails.mockReturnValue({ ...data, status: 1 })
    const { baseElement } = renderWithWrappers(<EditUserModal {...props} />)
    expect(baseElement).toMatchSnapshot()
  })

   it('renders modal body and footer correctly when status is inactive', async () => {
     getUserDetails.mockReturnValue({ ...data, status: 2 })
     renderWithWrappers(<EditUserModal {...props} />)
   })
```

As you can see I mocked the return value in two different `it` tests(the `status` value is different), but when I run the tests it seems for the second `it` test the returned `status` value is still `1` instead of `2` even though I set the `status` is `2` for the `mockReturnValue` function.

Comment: the mock cleanup seems the issue here. try resetting the mocks with `jest.resetAllMocks()` or `jest.restoreAllMocks()` in the `afterEach`.

Comment: @Kiran Parajuli I tried, still not working...